# T sql select 2 same datetime

Tags: sql-server

I have table called "**Customers**"

**Customer** table has below column

```
CreatedDate (datetime)
```

Customer table has below data

```
2011-01-06
2013-01-02 
2010-01-03 
2014-01-04 
2013-01-02 
2011-01-06
2010-01-03 
2014-01-04
```

**Question:**

How can i select from Customer Table as below

```
2010-01-03 
2010-01-03 

2011-01-06
2011-01-06

2013-01-02 
2013-01-02 

2014-01-04 
2014-01-04
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC`

Comment: What do you mean by the gaps?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT fields
FROM Customer
--WHERE 
ORDER BY CreatedDate
```